# segmentation fault looping fgets

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm getting a segmentation fault, and I suspect it is within the while loop, since commenting out the while looping allows it to run with one line read.  The goal of the program is to take 3 arguments, a text file name, a word, and a word to replace the first word with.  So ./this text old NEW  will replace all the first instances of the word old per line with NEW, all caps.  I'm only interested in the first instance per line, as per instructions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;           // file pointer
    char output[400];       // we put a limit on the size of our string so we don't go overboard
    char term[40];          // our term to search for
    char newTerm[40];       // the replacement term
    char filename[40];      // the name of the file we examine
    char curr[150];         // the current line of text read
    char currWord[40];      // current token
    char *cp;           // char pointer
    int replaceCounter;     // count how many strings were replaced
    int i = 0;          // index counter
    strncpy(filename, argv[1], 40); // assign the first argument to the filename
    strcat(filename, ".txt");   
    strncpy(term, argv[2], 40);
    strncpy(newTerm, argv[3], 40);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        printf("File opened successfully!\n");  
        while(fgets(curr, 150, fp) != NULL)
        {
            if((cp = strstr(curr, term)) != NULL);
                strncpy(cp, newTerm, strlen(newTerm));
            printf("%s\n", curr);
            fflush(fp);
        }

    }   
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file: %s", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;   

}
```

Using Ubuntu and gcc to compile, so I don't get anything more specific such as debugging.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are no checks on how many arguments are passed on the command line....

Comment: If your instructor said you can't use a debugger like gdb, drop the class; they're a sadist. Such a tool would near-*instantly* tell you where your problem is.

Comment: Look at semicolon after if condition `if((cp = strstr(curr, term)) != NULL);`  <- it should not be here .

Comment: This is a course based on introductory concepts of UNIX systems, the Bourne-Again Shell and C language.  This early in the course, we're not expected to check command line arguments, and we can use debuggers, but I don't know a good one that allows command line arguments, I'll try gdb.  Thanks for quick responses.

Comment: Solved now, the semi-colon was the issue, thanks rafix07!

Comment: And fyi, `strncpy` is near-useless (and flat-out dangerous) if you're not ensuring the string is properly terminated afterward. It's no silver bullet, and has an interesting, for-whatever-reason little-known behavior: it *always* writes N chars (the final parameter) one way or another. If the string is equal or greater than N length, it writes N, and doesn't terminate the string. If it is less, it tail fills with nullchars. The latter always seems to escape people.

Comment: "based on introductory concepts of... C language.... we're not expected to check command line arguments" -- note that checking how many arguments are passed is as simple as checking `argc`, and this _is_ an introductory C concept: `if (argc < 4) { /* print usage message and exit */ }`. Simple error checking should _never_ be ignored, even in toy programs, and this can save _many_ headaches when debugging. Also note that gdb does work with command-line arguments.

Comment: What happens if `argv[1]` is `40` chars or more with `strncpy(filename, argv[1], 40);` followed by `strcat(filename, ".txt");`?? (e.g. where does `strcat` stop scanning for the end of `filename`??) And **don't use magic numbers in your code**. If you need constants, `#define` them, or use an enum, e.g. `enum { NAMESZ = 40, LINESZ = 150, OUTSZ = 400 };`